# TypeError: Cannot set property 'chat_room_id' of undefined when using ng-if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular, angular-ng-if

I'm running into a bit of a road block here.

I'm working on a chat feature, which is currently within a rails partial in the application.html.erb file.

What I'm looking to do is have a list of a user's friends display in the chat area initially. When the user clicks on a friend's name, the corresponding chat room opens and the messages between the user and friend are displayed. If the user wishes to exit the chat, and view his friends list again, the user would simply click a button (currently "View Friends").

I am currently toggling between friends and rooms/messages using the ng-if directive.

I have not completely set this up yet, so I know there are bugs. I have created user friendships within rails, set up my REST API in rails, and can GET and POST resources via Angular and Restangular.

However, the issue at hand is that ever since I implemented the ng-if directives in the partial, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'chat_room_id' of undefined
```

If I am to remove the ng-if directives and all of the corresponding $scope.messagesVisible and $scope.friendsVisible variable references within the controller, the form submit works, so I know it has something to do with my implementation of the ng-if directives, and the fact that newMessage is undefined, but I'm not sure why.

I suspect it has something to do with Angular promises or my lack of understanding in regards to both Angular promises and the ng-if directive, but if anyone could shed some light on why this may be happening (and offer a solution) that would be amazing.

Thanks, guys!

Code below (please excuse terrible styling - it's a placeholder)

rails_partial:

```
<section ng-app="atmosphere" ng-controller="AtmoChatCtrl" style="position:relative; top:32%; float:right; right:5px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:30px;">
  <div ng-if="friendsVisible" style="position:relative; left:35px; width:100px;"> 
    <% user_friendships.each do |friendship| %>
      <ul>
        <% friend = friendship.friend %>
        <% if friendship.accepted? %>
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="setChatAttributes(<%= friend.id %>, <%= current_user.id %> );"><%= friend.name %></li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="messagesVisible" style="position:absolute; top:60%; width: 150px; height:40%; right:-80px; margin-top:100px">
    <div>
      <p ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message.user_id}}: {{message.body}}</p>
        <form ng-submit="saveMessage();">
          <input type="text" ng-model="newMessage.body">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:300px;">
    <button ng-if="messagesVisible" ng-click="viewFriends();">View Friends</button>
  </div>
</section>
<%= javascript_include_tag "angular/application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular-resource.min.js" %>
```

angular_controller:

```
angular.module('AtmoChatCtrl', [])
  .controller('AtmoChatCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$interval','Pusher','Restangular', function ($scope, $resource, $interval, Pusher, Restangular) {

    $scope.baseMessages = Restangular.one('api/chat_rooms', 2).all('chat_messages');
    $scope.roomId = '2';
    $scope.messagesVisible = false;
    $scope.friendsVisible = true;

    console.log("SET ROOM");

    $interval(function(){
      $scope.baseMessages.getList().then(function(messages) {
        $scope.messages = messages;
      });

      console.log("POLLING");
    }, 1000);


    $scope.saveMessage = function() {
      $scope.newMessage.chat_room_id = $scope.roomId;
      $scope.newMessage.user_id = $scope.userId;
      $scope.baseMessages.post($scope.newMessage).then(function(newMessage){
                $scope.messages.push(newMessage);
                console.log("SAVED");
            })
    }

    $scope.setChatAttributes = function(roomId, userId) {
      $scope.baseMessages = Restangular.one('api/chat_rooms', roomId).all('chat_messages');
      $scope.roomId = roomId;
      $scope.userId = userId;
      $scope.messagesVisible = true;
      $scope.friendsVisible = false;
      console.log(roomId)
      console.log(userId)
    }

    $scope.viewFriends = function() {
      $scope.friendsVisible = true;
      $scope.messagesVisible = false;
    }

  }]);
```

Comment: where have you defined `$scope.newMessage` object inside  `$scope.saveMessage` ?

Comment: @aseferov Hello! I guess I haven't! (doh!) After adding $scope.newMessage = {}; to the beginning of the function $scope.saveMessage I no longer see the error, but when I submit the message it properly submits the message's chat_room_id and user_id but not the body of the message. No error, just a message with no body.

Comment: NVM. I'm an idiot. Solved by setting `$scope.newMessage = {};` after the first `$scope.friendsVisible = true;`

Answer (score 0):

NVM. I'm an idiot. Solved by setting `$scope.newMessage = {};` after the first `$scope.friendsVisible = true;`